# SQL Efficiency maybe I should use Exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the following schema:

```
create table awards(
aid int primary key
, name varchar(100) not null );

create table institutions(
iid int primary key
, name varchar(100) not null );

create table winners(
aid int
, iid int
, year int
, filmname varchar(100)
, personname varchar(100)
, primary key (aid, iid, year)
, foreign key tid references awards(aid)
, foreign key cid references institutions(iid) );
```

I created the following query:

```
SELECT nominees.personname as personname, awards.name as award, nominees.year as year 

FROM nominees, institutions, awards WHERE institutions.iid = nominees.iid and 
awards.aid = nominees.aid and personname is not null 

GROUP BY nominees.personname, awards.name, nominees.year 

HAVING ((awards.name, count(DISTINCT institutions.name)) in 
(SELECT awards.name as 
awards, count(DISTINCT institutions.name) 
FROM nominees, awards, institutions 
WHERE nominees.aid = awards.aid and nominees.iid = institutions.iid 
GROUP BY awards.name)) 

ORDER BY nominees.personname, awards.name;
```

This query is designed to find all awards in which a single person has been nominated by every institution giving that award in a specific year. It essentially takes one person and counts the number of institutions that gave them a single award and compares that value to the max number of institutions that give that award.

The desired output should look something like the following:

```
"personname"    "award" "year"

"Alexandre"     "score" "2011"
"Skyfall"       "song"  "2013"
"Tangled"       "song"  "2011"
```

This gives the sets that I desire however I'm not sure whether or not it would be more efficient to do it a different way. I've attempted to get it to work with EXISTS but I didn't have much luck.

Main Question: Is there a more efficient way to do this query?

Comment: My mind glazed over! There's no explanation of what the query is supposed to do. You're not using explicit JOINs, which is quaintly 90's-style SQL.  The SQL formatting leaves a lot to be desired; the WHERE clause should at least start a new line, and the sub-query in the HAVING clause should be indented.  Without at least some explanation of what the query is doing and probably outline schemas of your tables indicating the relevant columns and the PKs and FKs, people probably aren't going to bother to spend the time working out what your query does and how it might be done better.

Comment: You should also supply `explain analyze` output for the query. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Formatting issues aside, I see your point, I'll make sure to edit my post so people might get a better understanding and therefore be able to help in a better manner. Also Craig Ringer, after looking at that link I'm not sure where to add the "explain analyze" in my query, but if I figure that out I'll edit that in as well.

Comment: Follow the links to the PostgreSQL documentation ([EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)) and you can see you write EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ...

Comment: There is *always* a more efficient way to do a query. Sometimes the more efficient method requires caching the results, so you don't actually do the query at all... What specific performance problem are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual with complex queries, I use TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design — to solve the problem in stages.  Each stage can be tested individually, and the results checked, ensuring that you reach the correct answer.

I note that you show us three tables; your query uses two of those but mentions a fourth, `nominees`.  I am assuming that `winners` is the same as `nominees`, since you gave us that schema and asked about who won the award from every institution offering the award in a given year.

#### Stage 1: How many institutions gave a specific award in a year?

```
SELECT aid, year, COUNT(*) AS num_awards
  FROM winners
 GROUP BY aid, year;
```

#### Stage 2: How many times did a person gain a specific award in a year?

```
SELECT aid, year, personname, COUNT(*) AS num_person_awards
  FROM winners
 GROUP BY aid, year, personname;
```

#### Stage 3: Rows where the two counts are the same?

```
SELECT n.aid, n.year, w.personname
  FROM (SELECT aid, year, COUNT(*) AS num_awards
          FROM winners
         GROUP BY aid, year
       ) AS n
  JOIN (SELECT aid, year, personname, COUNT(*) AS num_person_awards
          FROM winners
         GROUP BY aid, year, personname
       ) AS w
    ON n.aid = w.aid AND n.year = w.year AND n.num_awards = w.num_person_awards
```

#### Stage 4: Replace award ID with award name in result set

```
SELECT a.name AS awardname, a.year, w.personname
  FROM (SELECT aid, year, COUNT(*) AS num_awards
          FROM winners
         GROUP BY aid, year
       ) AS n
  JOIN (SELECT aid, year, personname, COUNT(*) AS num_person_awards
          FROM winners
         GROUP BY aid, year, personname
       ) AS w
    ON n.aid = w.aid AND n.year = w.year AND n.num_awards = w.num_person_awards
  JOIN awards AS a
    ON a.aid = n.aid;
```

I've not experimented with whether this is faster than your query, but it looks simpler, so I think it has a reasonable chance of working faster.

---

This is how I'd format your query:

```
SELECT nominees.personname AS personname, awards.name AS award, nominees.year AS year
  FROM nominees
  JOIN institutions ON institutions.iid = nominees.iid
  JOIN awards ON awards.aid = nominees.aid
 WHERE personname IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY nominees.personname, awards.name, nominees.year 
HAVING (awards.name, COUNT(DISTINCT institutions.name) IN 
            (SELECT awards.name AS awards, COUNT(DISTINCT institutions.name) 
               FROM nominees, awards, institutions 
              WHERE nominees.aid = awards.aid and nominees.iid = institutions.iid 
              GROUP BY awards.name)
 ORDER BY nominees.personname, awards.name;
```